# Android studio tablerow many buttons

Tags: android-studio, tablerow

Problem - I want to add 12 buttons to my table row (Android studio), but button width never gets small enough to fit all in there. I can only fit 3 buttons in vertical view.

Question - Is there a proper way to fit them in? Button texts will be integer numbers, so don't need a lot of space.

Comment: other buttons drive over right side of screen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this as the basis.

Basically it's setting the **`width`** to **`0DP`** and then using **`weight`** for distribution within the **`TableRow`**.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TableRow>
            <Button
                android:width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="1"/>
            <Button
                android:width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="2"/>
            <Button
                android:width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>
            <Button
                android:width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>
            <Button
                android:width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>
            <Button
                android:width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>
            <Button
                android:width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>
            <Button
                android:width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>
            <Button
                android:width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>
            <Button
                android:width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>
            <Button
                android:width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>
            <Button
                android:width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

I've only setup the text for the first 2.

You may have an issue with the size of the text though.

Comment: Hi, thanks for answer, it was layout_width which was needed to set to 0dp, then it works well.